# How to create service-connection-point(scp) for windows service on Active Directrory?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, active-directory

I have 1 windows service written in C#. I want to create Service-Connection-Point for this service when i install it. This scp should be created in 1 Organizational Unit on Active directory. Anybody know how to accomplish this.
Thanks!

Comment: Which .NET LDAP API are you using? It will be different in each.
That said, it's just like creating any other object type....SCP is not special...

Comment: Thanks,i got answer, it is same as creating other objects using DirectoryEntry class.